# "Show removed posts" should hide original vote as well as the undoing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph

The reputation page under a profile now has a "Show removed posts" tick box, which allows you to hide the "removed" activity on votes.

However, it doesn't hide the actual vote cast on the deleted post, which, for me, is nonsensical.

If I untick "Show removed posts", I expect *all* activity on removed posts to be hidden from my reputation page.

I.e **currently** if I have "Show removed posts" ticked, I see a downvote and a removal of a downvote (as the post was deleted);

[image]

If I then untick "Show removed posts", **only** the removal is hidden;

[image]

What I would ***expect*** to happen however, is for both the downvote *and* the removal to be hidden; I'm indicating I want to hide removed posts... so I want to hide *all* activity on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense, given the totals don't add up otherwise...when "show removed posts" isn't checked we now hide both post deletions *and* the votes that went with that post.

Comment: Nick, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125031/reputation-tab-says-ive-been-downvoted-but-it-shows-that-i-havent-been-at-the) is the same case, I think you've just killed two birds with one stone.