# Reputation tab says I've been downvoted, but it shows that I haven't been at the same time

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619470/1044146) have been downvoted according to [my reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1044146/martin?tab=reputation). However, when I go directly to that post and try to expand votes, there's no dowvnote and two upvotes. Oh, now I noticed it says that I've been both upvoted and downvoted at the same second.

We all know that 10 + 20 - 2 = 28, but reputation tab says it's 30, which would be okay, without the downvote.

[image: screenshot of reputation tab]

In `/reputation` page, I don't see any downvote. Reputation tab seems to be only point on Stack Overflow which thinks that I've been downvoted.

How is this possible?

Comment: Probably a mis-click that was quickly corrected, but there ought to be an "undownvoted" there too then.

Comment: I wonder if going straight from down to up vote skips the undownvote

Comment: @JeffMercado: I know about this. Have you read my question?

Comment: @awoodland: it does. Tried it on you

Comment: Just tried it on this question - what did it show?

Comment: @awoodland: just upvote. Downvote has been deleted permanently

Comment: @martin - assuming one of [those](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M0vSO.png) was you I'm not seeing the same thing here.

Comment: @awoodland: I downvoted and upvoted in the same minute - you see the same as me

Comment: Looks to be fixed, I'm seeing 28 now.

Comment: @JNK: My answer was downvoted. I removed it, but it's still visible in reputation tab, for some case. Is it for you ?:

Comment: I can't repro anything like this...

Comment: @NickCraver: this looks fixed already. So I assume status-completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever caused this, it looks like other shuffles in recent code changes to the UI fixed it, so making this status-completed.  If it crops up again (outside a 5 min deletion window), ping me via a comment here.