# Removed acceptance votes show regardless of whether the removed posts box is checked

Tags: bug

I just found out about the `show removed posts` checkbox on the reputation tab (thank you).  I've noticed though, that if you answered a question and had your answer accepted then the question is subsequently removed, the unaccept vote shows regardless of whether this box is checked or not.  It seems odd that some loss of rep would show for a removed post if you aren't showing all of it.

Comment: Duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125011/167443

Comment: I'd say related.  In this case it's showing me the removed accept as well as (presumably, as I didn't check) the original accept vote. The fix might be the same, though; it should probably show neither if the box is unchecked.